# Limit number of page visits based on ip

Tags: php

I wanted to know how can I prevent a single ip address from using too much bandwidth and rapidly access my webpages. That is, checking the user's ip address (I think `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`?), check for latest visit from this user, compute time difference and block rendering the page if the interval is short. Am I right? If so, how can I do it without consuming too much resource and/or time on the server? If there is a database approach, isn't it going cause too many locks?

Comment: If a single user really wants to attack your site in this way, a simple PHP IP block is not going to stop them. Especially since the request is already into PHP and has used resources anyways.

Comment: your missing the most important stuff, is the server yours eg VPS, dedicated or you have access to the firewall and/or you can apt-get packages? or just managed shared hosting

Comment: The server is dedicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache mod_bandwidth allows to control certain IPs

i.e. `BandWidth <domain|ip|all> <rate>`

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ratelimit.html

Comment: Your right, if the request hits php then the attacker has already won.

Comment: I like to limit the client before accessing the PHP but I don't want to just limit the bandwidth that they're using. Suppose there is a client that is implemented like a simple multithreaded crawler and it's downloading all of the pages in my website. Who can I prevent it?

Answer (score 6):

The best approach depends on who you're trying to block. If it's genuine users who are constantly refreshing the page, then (a) do you really want to block them - they're your users!?, and (b) You can use a session-based approach to avoid DB hits. If it's bots then you can't rely on sessions (because they may not be sending the session headers, or they may be currently but are malicious bots who will get around it).

If it is genuine users, then assuming you're OK with setting session cookies, you'll want something like this:

```
<?php
$min_seconds_between_refreshes = 3;

session_start();

if(array_key_exists('last_access', $_SESSION) && time()-$min_seconds_between_refreshes <= $_SESSION['last_access']) {
  // The user has been here at least $min_seconds_between_refreshes seconds ago - block them
  exit('You are refreshing too quickly, please wait a few seconds and try again.');
}
// Record now as their last access time
$_SESSION['last_access'] = time();
?>
```

If it's bots then you'll probably implement a database-based solution with similar logic.

In fact the correct solution in both cases is probably a caching proxy server in front of your application server. This will reduce load on your main app server and mean you won't have to worry so much about situations like this.

Comment: I want to block the *evil* users/bots who may want to use all my server's bandwidth with a simple crawler. What about the overhead of the database approach?

Comment: Right, so the sessions approach won't work. DB will have some overhead, but you're probably hitting the DB several times per request anyway? One extra won't make much difference. However, it'll be an ugly table, and you'll have to write something to clear out old visitors periodically. The solution by @eugene seems best to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the flood detection code that uses [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php). If the user exceeds 50 visits within a minute, he's blokcked for 300 seconds. Remote address is used to identify the client.

```
<?php 

$limit = 50; 
$seconds = 60;  
$block_for_seconds = 300;

$status = 'OK';

$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$r = $memcache->get($ip, array('c', 't'));

$c = 1; // count
$init_time = time();
if($r) {
  $s = $r[3]; // status
  $c = $r[0]+1;
  $init_time = $r[1];
  if($s == 'TOO_MANY_REQUESTS') {
    $d = time()-$r[1]; // time since block
    if($block_for_seconds-$d > 0) {  // still blocked
      die('Flood detected!! You are going to wait '.($block_for_seconds-$d).' and try again.');
    } else {  // block is over
      $status = 'OK';
      $init_time = time();
      $c = 0;
    }
  }

  $new_time = time();
  if($c > $limit) {  // check if happened within a minute
    $time_elapsed = $new_time - $init_time;
    if($time_elapsed < $seconds) {  
      $status = 'TOO_MANY_REQUESTS'; 
    }
    print "time elapsed: $time_elapsed, count:$c";
    $c = 0;
    $init_time = time();
  }
}
print_r($r);
$memcache->set($ip, array($c, $init_time, $new_time, $status) );
?>
```